# Excel VBA hangs on DDEInitiate()

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg, dde

I have the following code in VBA to connect to Bloomberg terminal:

```
Dim Blp As Long
Blp = DDEInitiate("Winblp", "bbk")

Call DDEExecute(Blp, "<Blp-1>" & "NAPMPMI" & "<INDEX>" & " DES<GO>")

Call DDETerminate(Blp)
```

Everytime Excel freezes on the DDEInitiate() part and it only works after I restart my computer or do a logoff and re-login.

I tried the following and they couldn't solve this issue:

1). Turn off some Excel and COM add-ins. I found the activated add-ins are the same when DDEInitiate works and when it stops working. So it doesn't seem to be Excel/COM add-ins that block DDEInitiate from running.

2). Kill all channels in the beginning of the code by doing:

```
Dim i, ChannelNumber As Integer
For i = 1 To 1000
    Application.DDETerminate (i) ' Closes all DDE links whose channels might be open
Next i
```

What else could I try and is there any alternatives to DDE that could send similar commands to bloomberg?